# how to create a opportunity converted from lead in test class

Tags: unit-test, lead-conversion

I am writing a test class and need to create test data on an opportunity converted from a lead.

I can create a lead in test class

```
Lead testLead = new Lead();
testLead.FirstName = 'Test First';
testLead.LastName = 'Test Last';
testLead.Company = 'Test Co';
insert testLead;
```

But not sure how to convert it to an opportunity.

Comment: Just to point out, that a lead is NOT converted into an opportunity - A lead is converted to an Account(or an existing one) and a contact. You can also create an opportunity on the same time.

Comment: The convert lead call creates an opportunity during the conversion by default.  See the documentation linked in Gaurav's answer below.

Comment: @E.J.Wilburn first line from the link: The convertLead DML operation converts a lead into an account and contact, as well as (optionally) an opportunity. - I stand by my comment: OPTIONALLY

Comment: Missed your second sentence for some reason, sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

This is done using the convertLead operation. It is documented at

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm

If you want to do it using a trigger, refer this [blog post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/02/13/enhancing-the-lead-convert-process-in-salesforce/).